# Security Exception

Tags: asp.net

I have a web application for upload video and images.In local server that working perfectly.But when i uploaded this to web server there is a error and i can't upload the files.The error is

```
Security Exception 
Description: The application attempted to perform an operation not allowed by the security policy.  To grant this application the required permission please contact your system administrator or change the application's trust level in the configuration file. 

Exception Details: System.Security.SecurityException: Request for the permission of type 'System.Security.Permissions.FileIOPermission, mscorlib, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' failed.

Source Error: 

The source code that generated this unhandled exception can only be shown when compiled in debug mode. To enable this, please follow one of the below steps, then request the URL:

1. Add a "Debug=true" directive at the top of the file that generated the error. Example:

  <%@ Page Language="C#" Debug="true" %>

or:

2) Add the following section to the configuration file of your application:

<configuration>
   <system.web>
       <compilation debug="true"/>
   </system.web>
</configuration>

Note that this second technique will cause all files within a given application to be compiled in debug mode. The first technique will cause only that particular file to be compiled in debug mode.

Important: Running applications in debug mode does incur a memory/performance overhead. You should make sure that an application has debugging disabled before deploying into production scenario.
```

I am using the code for uploading is..

```
Dim connectionstring As String = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("UploadConnectionString").ConnectionString
                    connection = New SqlConnection(connectionstring)
                    Dim cmd As New SqlCommand("insert into FileM (FileName,[File],FilePath,FileSize)" + "values(@FileName,@File,@FilePath,@FileSize)", connection)
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@FileName", SqlDbType.NVarChar, buffer.Length).Value = FileUpload1.FileName
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@File", SqlDbType.VarBinary).Value = buffer
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@FileSize", SqlDbType.BigInt).Value = file.ContentLength
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@FilePath", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = path
                    Using connection
                        connection.Open()
                        Dim i As Integer = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery

                    End Using
```

There have any issue with this type of uploading or want to insert into table via bussiness logic layer?

Answer (score 1):

This error is probably due to the fact that the account your application runs under doesn't have permissions to write to the directory you are trying to store the files.

Comment: Grant the account your your application runs under read/write permissions to the directory you are storing the files.

Comment: From the snippet you've uploaded it seems that you are storing the file into a database which should be fine. The only thing that's not clear is the `path` variable you are using. How is this variable initialized?

Comment: Dim path As String = Server.MapPath("../UpFiles/" + FileUpload1.FileName)

Comment: I think it is `Server.MapPath` that throws the exception as it is trying to get a folder name that probably it doesn't have permissions to read. You could verify that by removing the `../` part but eventually you might need to ask your hosting provider about granting permissions.